# Bad Request Size Request header field exceeds server limit. Authorization

Tags: node.js, express, server

I had call the Login POST API successfully. Every time user logins, they are given access_token which will be attached to Authorization header. The problem right now is when they get into the authenticated pages. When the API starts to call, I got Bad Request Size of request header field exceeds server limit. Authorization. Currently I'm using ExpressJS JSONWebToken module to generate token.

**How I generate token**

```
 var token = jwt.sign(user, config.user_secret, {
      expiresIn: '1440m'
 });
```

**Middleware**

```
var token = req.body.access_token || req.query.access_token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization'];
 
// decode token
if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, config.user_secret, function(err, decoded){
           if(err){
               return res.json({
                   returnCode: -1,
                   returnMessage: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
               });
           }else{
               req.decoded = decoded;
               current_user_id = req.decoded._doc._id;
               next();
           }
        });
}else{
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            returnCode: -1,
            returnMessage: 'No token provided.'
        });
}
```

**Problem**

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
>
> Authorization

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Same problem with my setup and no solution. Seems to be more related to client browser issue.